# How to upload bulk products in Magento (not from import/export option)

Tags: php, sql-server, magento, magento-1.7

I want to upload bulk amount of products into my  magento store.
for ex - more than 200 000 - 300 000.

I have search many option like MAGMI and also from magento backend like import/export option.

but this is not a good solution in this situation ..

I studied about some sql that provide pretty much faster operation.

Refer.

http://www.extensionhut.com/blog/magento-direct-sql-queries/

http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/direct-sql-queries/

As I am newbie in this magento environment. I don’t know how and where to put this code and magneto and to execute this code. Do I need to create a module for this? How can I run this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Bulk amount of Data from CSV file - follow this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/439843/Handling-BULK-Data-insert-from-CSV-to-SQL-Server)

```html
BULK INSERT dbo.TableForBulkData
FROM 'C:\BulkDataFile.csv'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

Hi Below is the script as per my requirement and new magento developer to write mysql queries outside or without magneto modules.

```html
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once("app/Mage.php");
//umask(0);

Mage::app('default');
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write'); 
$sql="select * from catalog_product_entity WHERE sku='demoproduct001'";
$value=$connection->query($sql); 
while ($row = $value->fetch())
 { 
print_r($row); 

echo "entity_id : ".$entity_id=$row['entity_id'];
 };

$sql1 = "UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_varchar` SET value='Demo Product1 New Content here ' WHERE attribute_id ='82' AND entity_id = ".$entity_id; 
$connection->query($sql1);

$sql3="select * from catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id ='82' AND entity_id = ".$entity_id;
$value=$connection->query($sql3); 
while ($row = $value->fetch())
 { 
print_r($row); 
 };

?>
```